# The program name is not shown with protocol handler in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, protocols, protocol-handler

Following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page, I could make "alert" protocol handler with Windows 7.

The registry setup is exactly the same as instructed in the page.
[image]

The problem is that the Program is not shown on dialog boxes both for IE and FF.

[image]
[image]

The protocol handler works fine.
[image]

What's wrong with this? Do I add something more in registry to show the program name?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of this, but have you tried to add a resource file containing the version information (including AppName, ProductName, etc) for your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be omitting the [version resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058%28VS.85%29.aspx) when linking your executable. That MSDN article includes the following sample resource:

```
#define VER_FILEVERSION             3,10,349,0
#define VER_FILEVERSION_STR         "3.10.349.0\0"

#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION          3,10,0,0
#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR      "3.10\0"

#ifndef DEBUG
#define VER_DEBUG                   0
#else
#define VER_DEBUG                   VS_FF_DEBUG
#endif

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION     VER_FILEVERSION
PRODUCTVERSION  VER_PRODUCTVERSION
FILEFLAGSMASK   VS_FFI_FILEFLAGSMASK
FILEFLAGS       (VER_PRIVATEBUILD|VER_PRERELEASE|VER_DEBUG)
FILEOS          VOS__WINDOWS32
FILETYPE        VFT_DLL
FILESUBTYPE     VFT2_UNKNOWN
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904E4"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName",      VER_COMPANYNAME_STR
            VALUE "FileDescription",  VER_FILEDESCRIPTION_STR
            VALUE "FileVersion",      VER_FILEVERSION_STR
            VALUE "InternalName",     VER_INTERNALNAME_STR
            VALUE "LegalCopyright",   VER_LEGALCOPYRIGHT_STR
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks1", VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS1_STR
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks2", VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS2_STR
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", VER_ORIGINALFILENAME_STR
            VALUE "ProductName",      VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR
            VALUE "ProductVersion",   VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR
        END
    END

    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        /* The following line should only be modified for localized versions.     */
        /* It consists of any number of WORD,WORD pairs, with each pair           */
        /* describing a language,codepage combination supported by the file.      */
        /*                                                                        */
        /* For example, a file might have values "0x409,1252" indicating that it  */
        /* supports English language (0x409) in the Windows ANSI codepage (1252). */

        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252

    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on David's link, I could make it shown with resource embedding.

`csc prosseek.cs /resource:prosseek.resource /win32icon:prosseek.ico`

[image]